# C# EF Core 8.0 not behaving like expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, c#-8.0

I'm using EF Core to work with data (and I'm new to EF). I have a `DbContext` that I use to get data from SQL Server. Once the data is loaded into memory, I change values on different rows but I'm not writing back the data back to SQL Server just yet (I want to write to DB when user will click the OK button only).

Here's precisely what is happening: I have a table called `Equipments` with a column `FkIdType`. I change the row `FkIdType` value from null to 5 for example:

```
var equ = DataAccess.GetEquipment(pkIdEqu);
equ.FkIdEquipmentType = (int)GVEquipmentTypes.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colPkId);
```

`DataAccess` is a helper class to only do a

```
context.Where(x => x.PkId == pkID).FirstOrDefault();
```

After that, I want to get a list of all `Equipments` where `FkIdType` is 5. The query is like this:

```
var query = context.Equipments.Where(x => x.FkIdType == 5);
query.ToList();
```

Here's the problem. If I put a break point and inspect `context.Equipments`, I can clearly see that the value has been changed. However, the query returns nothing (if it's the only row with `FkIdType` with a value of 5). Why?

I tried changing the value directly in the database (manually with SSMS) and it seems that the query is actually looking in the database and not in the local context. I don't understand why.

Here's what I tried:

1. Force the `ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`
2. Tried using `context.Database.BeginTransaction();`
3. Getting access to the data the "other side". I mean by this using the Types table like this:

```
Types.Where(x => x.PkId == FkIdType)
     .Select(x => x.Equipments).ToList();
```

But the same weird thing happens. If I execute the code, the list is empty. If I "inspect" the `Types` object and open the "Result Views" property in break mode, then I see the data and then the query return a list with the expected data... Why?

Comment: Careful with the debugger.  When you inspect the results, an IEnumerable result will get iterated by the debugger.  Nothing is left for the program when you resume after the breakpoint, ToList() on the IEnumerable will produce an empty list.  Be sure to take the warning "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" serious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the behaviour might feel wrong, it is behaving in an explainable way. The issue is that while you are modifying a tracked entity, and EF will return that tracked entity in place of a data read, it will only do so if that record is identified by the data read.

When you run:

```
var query = context.Equipments.Where(x => x.FkIdType == 5);
query.ToList();
```

This generates an SQL Query similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].Equipments WHERE FkIdType == 5
```

Here lies the problem. EF will go to the database to try and find any matching rows. Regardless of whether it finds any or not, it will *not* find the row you have a change pending for. EF will substitute any entities it reads with entities it is tracking, but it will not scan the tracking cache as part of the query. If you had queried the rows by some other common identifier where the modified row was returned from the SQL query, your tracked, modified entity with the FkIdType of 5 would have been swapped out in the results.

One work-around for this would be that if you have potentially modified state to include, to load the data into the tracking cache then explicitly query the tracking cache:

```
context.Equipments.Where(x => x.FkIdType == 5).ToList();
var equipments = context.Equipments.Local
    .Where(x => x.FkIdType == 5).ToList();
```

Here the first query executes and would load the selected items into the tracking cache by default. The second statement executes against the local tracking cache, which includes the newly loaded entities, as well as any potentially modified entities. Ultimately though it is best to finalize the update state with a `SaveChanges()` before reading data. Leaving modified rows in the change tracking for any amount of time can end up leading to poisoned DbContexts where a tracked change becomes invalid and sitting there, blocking a future `SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: Steve, thank you for your detailed answer it really helped! That's exactly what I was looking for. Following your explanation, I searched for a proper design pattern to work with local data in EF (letting user work temporarily on local data and decide if the data needs to be push to de DB at the end). I found this useful link :  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957036/implementing-the-repository-pattern-correctly-with-ef-core)